# Why can't $\sin(1/x)$ be differentiated?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, trigonometry

I've read in textbooks that $\sin(\frac 1x)$ can't be differentiated because it oscillates too rapidly, but so what? Why does oscillation stop it from being differentiated?

Comment: This function is only not differentiable at $0$. Now, if the function is differentiable, then we often have a good idea if not about the value of the slope, but at least whether it is positive (function grows) or negative. What do you think the sign of the slope this function has at zero?

Comment: That function is in fact differentiable everywhere on its domain (that is, outside the point $0$). And it cannot be extended contiuously at $0$ (while continuity is prerequisite for differentiability). A more interesting example would be $x\sin(1/x)$ extended continuously at $0$ (that is, defined to be $0$ there).

Comment: @MarcvanLeeuwen If we designate the sin(1/x) function's value at 0 to be 0, can it be differentiated at 0?

Comment: @S.Mo, what is $\infty\times\sin\infty$?

Comment: @S.Mo However we define the function at $0$ (in particular if we define it to be $0$ there), it will not be continuous at $0$ (that is what I meant by "it cannot be extended contiuously at $0$"). And not being continuous, it will _a fortiori_ not be differentiable.

Comment: What the textbook probably said was: when the definition of this function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is extended using $f(0)=0$, the resulting function $f(x)$ is not differentiable at $x=0$.

Comment: Which textbooks would that be? Please give a specific reference. Moreover are there any example of non-differentiable functions you are familiar with? If so which?

Comment: You should burn your textbook.

Comment: The function $\begin{cases}\sin1/x,&x\ne0\\c,&x=0\end{cases}$ is not differentiable at $0$, no matter what you choose for $c$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The function $f(x)=\sin(1/x)$ is trivially not differentiable at $0$ since it is not defined there. However we will prove that there is no possible value for $c$ so that
$$g(x) = \left\{\begin{array}{l l} \sin(1/x) & \qquad \text{if $x \neq 0$}\\
c & \qquad \text{if $x=0$}       
\end{array}\right.$$
is continuous at $0$ (and hence, see (A) below, can't be differentiable at $0$). To do so we will show that the $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

**Proof:** Let $\epsilon = \frac{1}{2}$. We will begin by showing that for each $\delta > 0$ there exists $x_1,x_2 \in (-\delta,\delta) \setminus \{0\}$ such that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)| > 2\epsilon$. Let $N=\lceil \frac{1}{2\pi \delta} \rceil + 1$. It follows that $2\pi N + \frac{\pi}{2} > \frac{1}{\delta}$ and $2\pi N +  \frac{3 \pi}{2} > \frac{1}{\delta}$. This means that $x_1= \frac{1}{2\pi N + \frac{\pi}{2}}$, $x_2 = \frac{1}{2\pi N + \frac{3\pi}{2}}$ are in $(-\delta,\delta)\setminus \{0\}$. Since $f(x_1)=1$ and $f(x_2)=-1$ we see that $|f(x_1)-f(x_2)|=2>1=2\epsilon$ as desired. Now let $c$ be an element of $\mathbb{R}$ we have (by the triangle inequality) that $2\epsilon <  |f(x_1) - f(x_2)| \leq |f(x_1) -c| + |f(x_2) - c|$ so that at least one of $|f(x_1)-c|$ or $|f(x_2) -c|$ must be greater than $\epsilon$.

We have proved that for each $c$ in $\mathbb{R}$, there exists $\epsilon >0$ such that for all $\delta >0$ there exists $x$ in $(-\delta,\delta)\setminus \{0\}$ such that $|f(x)-c|>\epsilon$, and hence by definition that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does not exist.

**(A)**
Let $f$ be a real valued function defined on an open interval containing $a$. If $f$ is differentiable at $a$, then $f$ is continuous at $a$.

**Proof:** Suppose $f$ is differentiable at $a$. Then by definition there exists $L$ such that $$\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}=L.$$
Using limit laws we have $$\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = \lim_{x\to a} f(x) -f(a) + f(a) = \lim_{x\to a} (f(x) -f(a)) + \lim_{x\to a} f(a) = \lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) -f(a)}{x-a}(x-a) + f(a)=\lim_{x\to a} \frac{f(x) -f(a)}{x-a}\lim_{x\to a}(x-a)+f(a)=L\times 0+f(a)=f(a)$$
and hence $f$ is continuous at $a$.

Answer (score 1):

The function can be differentiated wherever it is defined: that is on the whole real line except $0$. At the point $0$, the derivative does not exist in the first place because the function is not defined there. If we extend the definition of the function by assigning a value to it at $0$, it still does not help in obtaining a derivative there, whatever value is chosen. This is essentially because of the oscillation that you mention, which grows ever wilder as $0$ is approached. From the definition of the derivative of a function $f$ at $0$, if it exists: $$f'(0)=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)-f(0)}{h}.$$But the limit cannot exist in this case because, however $f(0)$ is chosen, the numerator will vary through a range, from $-1-f(0)$ to $1-f(0)$, and so does not tend to $0$, while the denominator does tend to zero. So the ratio oscillates over an ever wider range as $h$ tends to $0$.

Comment: @ John Bentin Even if it oscillates too fast, what's the harm? Left hand and right hand limits can still, in theory, be calculated because distances can be made arbitrarily small.

Comment: @S.Mo: I have added a more detailed explanation. I hope that it is clear now.

Comment: So then it's impossible to approach a certain y value from both sides even if we make the x values so small that they're almost the same?

Comment: Can't we at least take left hand and right limits at 0?

Comment: @S.Mo: To answer your first question: Yes, it's impossible to approach any fixed $y$ value as $x$ approaches $0$; the $y$ values jump up and down ever more rapidly the closer $x$ is to $0$. Regarding your second question, the situation on the left is just as bad as on the right; only the sign changes:$$\sin\frac1{-x}=-\sin\frac1x.$$

Comment: how do you prove that a limit at 0 doesn't exist? I'd like to see some kind of mathematical reasoning, ya know?

Comment: @S.Mo: I have posted the mathematical reasoning above. That's my best shot. Sorry if you still don't get it.

Comment: In my opinion you have not provided mathematical reasoning, only intuition. You haven't proved any of the claims you make.

Comment: OK, @Nex. Why don't you post your answer and show us what your idea of a proof is?

Comment: @JohnBentin See my answer below.

Comment: @Nex: Your proof is rigorous and correct.

Answer (score 1):

The function $f(x) = \sin(1/x)$ is differentiable on it's domain. The derivative is
$$
f'(x) = \cos(1/x)\frac{d}{dx}\frac{1}{x} = -\frac{1}{x^2}\cos\left(\frac{1}{x}\right).
$$
This derivative exists everywhere except at $x=0$. Note that the function $f(x)$ isn't defined at $0$. A function that is differentiable at a point is in particular defined at that point. So there is no problems with things oscillating to fast.

Comment: Why the downvote?

Answer (score -2):

Differentiation is rigourously defined by taking limits; because of the *increasing* rapidity of oscillation of $sin(1/x)$ as one approaches the origin, the limit that defines the derivative there doesn't converge.